# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds .. syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1. the code is a follows   where i get the error and that is come going from  http://cms2.br-de.tk/editinfo.php to http://cms2.br-de.tk/updateinfo.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com","******_12","*******") or       die("Error:".mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("******_1");//add your dbname

    //get the variables we transmitted from the form
    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $Author = $_POST['Author'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Content = $_POST['Content'];

    //replace TestTable with the name of your table
    //replace id with the ID of your user
    $sql = "UPDATE `posts` SET `Tilte` = '$Tilte',`Author` = '$Author',`Date` =   '$Date',`Content` = '$Content' WHERE `posts`.`ID` = '$ID' 1 ";

     mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    echo "Database updated. <a href='editinfo.php'>Return to edit info</a>";

?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ — Do not use `mysql_*`, do not build SQL by mashing strings together.

Comment: get rid of the "1" in your query `$sql` string and also get rid of the single quote symbols by escaping them since you'll search for a Title that's equal to the literal string $Title instead of your `$_POST['Title']` value.

Comment: I second what @Quentin said, google for cross site scripting and sanitizing your sql queries + escaping strings. Etc, there are tons of resources. If you want to play around with something that will utterly fail from a security point of view, you can do it, but it will be of didactic value only.

Comment: now getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a8501122/public_html/cms2/updateinfo.php on line 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added additional 1 at the end of query. It should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `posts` SET `Tilte` = '$Title',`Author` = '$Author',`Date` =   '$Date',`Content` = '$Content' WHERE `posts`.`ID` = '$ID'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spare `1` at the end of your statement.

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `Tilte` = '$Title',`Author` = '$Author',`Date` =   '$Date',`Content` = '$Content' WHERE `posts`.`ID` = '$ID';"
```

As Grigore correctly spotted, you might also have a typo in your statement depending on your column names.

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `Title` = '$Title',`Author` = '$Author',`Date` =   '$Date',`Content` = '$Content' WHERE `posts`.`ID` = '$ID';"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`Tilte` = '$Title'
```

maybe this is title not tilte, besides that there's a "1" right at the ending of the query